# how to get path of uploaded file in servlet from jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

in my jsp page

```
<form action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file"name="file" size="50" /> 
<tr>
<td align="Center"><input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
```

how to get this uploaded file path in servlet.

Comment: What library do you use in your jsp to upload files?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy i used poi library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the File Upload API in Servlet 3.0 you can retrieve the file name from the content-disposition header like so:

```
    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
          String fileName = retrieveFileName(part);
    }


    private String retrieveFileName(Part part) {
          String contentDisposition = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
          String[] items = contentDisposition.split( ";");
           for (String str : items) {
                  if (str.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                        return str.substring(str.indexOf("=" ) + 2, str.length() - 1);
                 }
          }
          return "" ;
   }
```

The servlet must be marked with the annotation: @MultipartConfig

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your upload.java

```
File uploadedFile = new File(fpath, fileName);
item.write(uploadedFile);
String f1 = uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Based on [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi) file up-loader.